# PHP importDump.php Mediawiki Import error Document is empty

Tags: php, mysql, import, mediawiki, dump

I am trying to import the mediawiki dump in fresh install of mediawiki, latest stable version.

```
[root@ maintenance]# php importDump.php < dump_en.xml.bz2
```

and I am getting

```
[root@ maintenance]# php importDump.php < dump_en.xml.bz2
PHP Warning:  XMLReader::read(): uploadsource://2fe09586b4f978244fd125df8178a93f:1: parser error : Document is empty in /var/www/public_html/includes/Import.php on line 449
Warning: XMLReader::read(): uploadsource://2fe09586b4f978244fd125df8178a93f:1: parser error : Document is empty in /var/www/public_html/includes/Import.php on line 449
PHP Warning:  XMLReader::read(): BZh91AY&SYцу[dЕЖ_ЪUЪЪЪЪЪЪЗ©ЪЪЪЪЪЪЪЪЪ· in /var/www/public_html/includes/Import.php on line 449
Warning: XMLReader::read(): BZh91AY&SYцу[dЕЖ_ЪUЪЪЪЪЪЪЗ©ЪЪЪЪЪЪЪЪЪ· in /var/www/public_html/includes/Import.php on line 449
PHP Warning:  XMLReader::read(): ^ in /var/www/public_html/includes/Import.php on line 449
Warning: XMLReader::read(): ^ in /var/www/public_html/includes/Import.php on line 449
PHP Warning:  XMLReader::read(): An Error Occured while reading in /var/www/public_html/includes/Import.php on line 449
Warning: XMLReader::read(): An Error Occured while reading in /var/www/public_html/includes/Import.php on line 449
[6c11e6cc] [no req]   Exception from line 453 of /var/www/public_html/includes/Import.php: Expected <mediawiki> tag, got
Backtrace:
#0 /var/www/public_html/maintenance/importDump.php(286): WikiImporter->doImport()
#1 /var/www/public_html/maintenance/importDump.php(253): BackupReader->importFromHandle(resource)
#2 /var/www/public_html/maintenance/importDump.php(97): BackupReader->importFromStdin()
#3 /var/www/public_html/maintenance/doMaintenance.php(113): BackupReader->execute()
#4 /var/www/public_html/maintenance/importDump.php(291): require_once(string)
#5 {main}
```

I have already set:

```
$wgShowExceptionDetails = true;
```

in `LocalSettings.php`

How can I import the dump in the media-wiki?

Comment: What MW version? How big is the bz2 file? And are you by any chance using WAMP?

Comment: @leo  MediaWiki 1.22.7 , bz2 file is 95 mb. and i am using cent os.

Comment: So that should be ok. Did you try with an unpacked file? Just in case it's bz2 that returns an empty result

Comment: @leo yes, i tried with unpacked file which becomes around 1GB and i got same result.

Comment: One more thing: What MW version is your dump from? (There can be problems using importDump across versions sometimes)

Comment: "BZh91AY&SYцу[dЕЖ_ЪUЪЪЪЪЪЪЗ©ЪЪЪЪЪЪЪЪЪ·" wth